# How to disable row header in devexpress xtragrid

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

Hai all,

I want to know how to disable row header in `Devexpress xtragrid` (grid control ) . In normal we are disabling the property of DataGrid by `row header visbile` into `false`.But how to disable in Devexpress.

Please Help

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At last i found the answer !!!

set the `GridView.OptionsView.ShowIndicator`  property to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you want to achieve, but to hide a column, you should set its Visible property to false.  I.e.

GridView1.Columns["SomeFieldName"].Visible = false;

If this does not help, please explain the needed functionality in greater details and I will update my answer....

Comment: please check ma EDIT question. I want to remove yellow highlighted portion of XtraGrid.

Comment: tnx for the help and i found answer .